# How to mock a global value for unit testing typescript?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I have a function written in typescript that I would like to unit test *with the unit test also written in typescript* that does similar to the following:

```
export function foo(): string {
  return window.navigator.userAgent
}
```

Typescript wraps this function in an IIFE and so I need a way to test the function with a mocked window.navigator.userAgent value.  Is there any simple way to do this with typescript?  I'd like to avoid bringing in a whole typescript mocking library if possible!

Comment: The [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) doesn't have the `userAgent` property, but the [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) does. But what exactly is the problem? Why do you need to mock any of those?

Comment: oops... also using window.location.search for another part of the function, mixed it up when re-writing code here (fixed now). the problem is that when I run the unit test it doesn't run in a browser so it says "window.navigator.userAgent does not exist" so I need to be able to provide a mocked value in the unit test

Comment: Currently my solution is to have another module that exports functions that return window.navigator.userAgent and window.location.search - and to mock that module in the unit test.  I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Where does it run? You can always mock that yourself, it's not much work, but maybe there are already some implementations, depending on your environment. The module you are loading (which mocks things) should just add things to the global scope because `window` is global.

Comment: The unit tests are running in Node using mocha/chai so window doesn't exist because they aren't running in a browser. Sorry if that wasn't clear before.

Comment: So you're in luck!  Such implementations are already available for you, for example [jsdom-global](https://github.com/rstacruz/jsdom-global). I haven't used it, but seems like it's what you're looking for. There are probably more implementations out there, you just need to search for them.

Comment: That worked great - thanks.  I had stumbled on it before but wanted to check if there was a way that didn't involve another dependency, but this is much better than my previously mentioned workaround.